# Loop won't break

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

The program is stuck at the first input, also won't respond to while True

```
available_toppings = ["mushrooms", "olives", "pepperoni", "pineapple"]
print(f"Hello! please choose from the available toppings:\n{available_toppings[0].title()}\n{available_toppings[1].title()}\n{available_toppings[2].title()}\n{available_toppings[3].title()}\n")
requested_toppings = input("Please choose your topping:\n")

def program():
            if requested_toppings in available_toppings:
                print(f"Adding {requested_toppings}..")
            else:
                print(f"Sorry, {requested_toppings} is not available!")

while True:
    program()
    if input("Do you want to add another topping? (Y/N)\n").strip().upper().lower() == "N":
        break
print("Finished making your pizza!")
```

The program should `print(f"Adding{requested_toppings}..")`  if the user input is a value that exists in `available_toppings` else `print(f"Sorry, {requested_toppings} is not available!")` if it's not. Then ask the user if they want to add another topping. If not (N), the loop breaks and `print("Finished making your pizza!")`
Instead it's stuck at the first input.

Comment: `upper().lower() == "N":`

Comment: That `.lower()` will cast your input string to lowercase, which always gets compared to a capital `N`, which will always return `False`. Removing it should solve your problem.

Comment: "Instead it's stuck at the first input." Did you try providing some input? What happens when you do so? Also, try to think carefully about the intended logic. Should `requested_toppings = input("Please choose your topping:\n")` happen **only once, no matter what**? Or should it happen again if the `requested_toppings` is not `in available_toppings`? (Or perhaps it should happen every time before `program` runs?) Therefore, where in the code should this be put - inside the loop, or outside/before?

Comment: Thanks, that solved the loop break issue, but it's still stuck at the first input: If I first type "mushrooms", it will still return "Adding mushrooms" when another input is given.

Comment: Well, yes. Again, think carefully about the logic. After you have added the mushrooms, should the program ask the user again for another topping? Or should it use the existing value of `requested_toppings` again? Therefore, do we need to call `input` again? Where in the code might that go?

Comment: Placing requested_toppings in the function solved the problem, thanks